# Как на Windows 10-11 продолжать выполнять консольную утилиту PowerShell при отключении по OpenSSH с возможностью подключения обратно?

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh

На мини ПК с Windows 11 и OpenSSH необходимо запустить консольное приложение PowerShell, чтобы по ssh (OpenSSH) можно было подключаться и управлять им, и чтобы оно продолжало работу в фоне, даже после отключения ssh сессии. Само приложение на PowerShell и управляется только из консоли с помощью горячих клавиш. Когда я подключаюсь по ssh, я могу запустить приложение, но при отключении ssh оно также завершится, а мне нужно, чтобы оно продолжало работу и чтобы я мог снова подключиться к нему по ssh.

В идеале бы что-то вроде screen/tmux под windows и powershell, чтобы можно было хотя бы локально на мини ПК запустить сессию screen/tmux с приложением, к которой можно было бы подключаться и по ssh.

К сожалению, Invoke-Command и Enter-PSSession мне не подходят, т.к. в них горячие клавиши работать не могут: горячим клавишам через `[Console]::KeyAvailable` нужно окно консоли, которое Invoke-Command и Enter-PSSession не предоставляют. Либо же нужен способ работы Invoke-Command и Enter-PSSession с предоставлением окна консоли для работы горячих клавиш (`[Console]::KeyAvailable`).

Comment: Есть ещё вариант с подсистемой Linux, в которой будет запущен tmux, в котором powershell, но это какие-то костыли и приведёт к лишней нагрузке, пусть и не большой. Возможно также придётся установить openssh в саму подсистему Linux, и таким образом будет избыточно 2 сервера openssh на одной машине. Не уверен в этом, не пробовал ещё такое.

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` после переподключения продолжает пробрасывать клавиши.